# Ransack showing all instead of filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am trying to use Ransack gem but it returns all 12,000 rows instead of using the filter.

Controller:

```html
 def list
  @q = LmiHost.ransack(params[:q])
  if !(params[:commit].nil?) then
   @computers = @q.result
  else
   @computers = LmiHost.where(:job_id => 121)
  end
 end
```

View:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#computer_search_results").dataTable();
});
</script>

<table id="computer_search_table">
 <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
 <tr><td>Project:</td><td><%= f.select :job_id, @project_job_selector %></td></tr>
 <tr><td><%= f.submit 'Search' %></td></tr>
 <%end%>
</table>


<table id="computer_search_results">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Lmi Name</th>
   <th>Service Tag</th>
   <th>Model</th>
   <th>Ship Date</th>
   <th>Warranty Date</th>
   <th>Project</th>
   <th>Invoice Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% @computers.each do |computer| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= computer.host_description %></td>
   <td><%= computer.host_service_tag %></td>
   <td><%= computer.host_model %></td>
   <td><%= computer.ship_date %></td>
   <td><%= computer.warranty_date %></td>
   <td><%= computer.job.name unless computer.job.nil? %></td>
   <td><%= computer.invoice_name %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

the URL looks okay after seraching:
[URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU73O.png)

But it is acting like :

```html
@computers = LmiHost.all
```

Any ideas as too why this is happening?

Comment: how is your params in log looks like ?

Comment: Started GET "/computer/list?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bjob_id%5D=1726&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-03 23:26:12 -0800
Processing by ComputerController#list as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"job_id"=>"1726"}, "commit"=>"Search"}

Comment: seems ok to my. Why not put a 'byebug' in list and debug with params[:q]
and @q.result to see what is exactly happening there.

Comment: (byebug) @q
Ransack::Search<class: LmiHost, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>
(byebug) @q.result
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LmiHost id: 1, A Lot of sensitive data, ...]>
(byebug) @q.result.count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `lmi_hosts`
12600
(byebug)

Comment: when you @q.result can you not see the sql statement generated by it? you can see what is happening there and figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are not specifying a proper matcher. if you want to select particular job id you should indicate the search matcher in the form.

for example you are saying `job_id` where it should be `job_id_eq` or what ever matcher you want it to be

where you should getter a Ransack Search item like following.

```
Ransack::Search<class: LmiHost, base: Grouping <conditions: [Condition <attributes: ["job_id"], predicate: eq, values: ["123"]>], combinator: and>>
```

in your Ransack search I don't see the predicate hence it returns all the resutls.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what this answer means. To elaborate a bit, in the view, `job_id` should be renamed to `job_id_eq`, where `eq` is one of the matchers specified here https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#search-matchers. If you want to match a text containing some value, use `job_description_cont` instead of `job_description` in the view.